# fullscreen scrolling background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, fullscreen

I am coding a website and what I would like to have is a series of background images that scroll. The tricky part is I have to background image set up to take up the entire screen without any scrolling bars on the right and bottom without loosing the aspect ratio.

(I used [this](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) figure out to get the background how I wanted it)

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slider1"><img src="background1.jpg" class="back"/></div>
        <div class="slider2"><img src="background2.jpg" class="back"/></div>
        <!-- <div class="slider3">slide3</div>
        <div class="slider4">slide4</div>
        <div class="slider5">slide5</div> -->
    </div>
</div><!--end bg-->
<div class="buttons">
<div class="left"><--</div>
<div class="right">-></div> 
</div>
```

my css:

```
.bg {
/* Set rules to fill background */
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: auto;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;

overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
    .bg {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
    }

}

img.back {
    /* Set rules to fill background */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;

/* Set up proportionate scaling */
width: 100%;
height: auto;

/* Set up positioning */
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
    img.back {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
    }
}


.slider{
width: 200%;
position: relative;
}
.slider1, .slider2, .slider3, .slider4, .slider5{
width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.buttons{
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left: 200px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

and my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var total = 2
var current = 1
$(".left").click(function(){
    if(current<total){
    current --
    $(".slider").animate({left:"-=100%"})
    }
})
    $(".right").click(function(){
        if(current>1){
        current ++
        $(".slider").animate({left:"+=100%"})
    }
})

})
```

Please let me know if what I am trying to do is possible! I think the main issue I am having right now is with the jquery and the animating with percentages.

Comment: Your jQuery code needs semicolons, I'm not sure if the script itself works, but at least the syntax has to be right.

Comment: I have used this exact jquery code but with the percentages as px and it works just fine! no semicolons needed.

Answer (score 0):

Height and width on percentage work only when its parent too have some height and width . So whenever you give height/width as percentage it search 1st weather its parent has height property or not and if there is also on percentage it traverse upword the DOM until it finds height/width in pixels(or other scale).

But in your case you dont know the actual height of window. So instead of giving height property you can calculate window size and assign it on div height as pixel.

This may work for you

**Css**

```
.bg {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
overflow: hidden;
}

.slider{
position:absolute;
}

.slider1,slider2{
float:left;
}

img.back{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
    function resizeBackGround(){
    var windowHeight=$(window).height();
    var windowWidth=$(window).width();

    $('.slider').css({
    width:(windowWidth*2)+'px', //take multiple according to number of background image you are using.
    height:windowHeight+'px'
    });
    $('.slider1,.slider2').css({
    width:windowWidth+'px',
    height:windowHeight+'px'
    });

    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
      resizeBackGround();
      $(window).resize(function(){
         resizeBackGround();
      });

});
```

After you can use your animate functions to switch background image.